# Very high validation loss/small train loss in Pytorch, while finetuning resnet 50

Tags: python, pytorch, transfer-learning, resnet

I am training model to classify 2 types of images. I have decided to take a transfer-learning approach, freeze every part of resnet50 and new layer and start finetuning process.  My dataset is not perfectly balanced but i used weights for that purpose.Please take a look at validation loss vs training loss graph. It seems to be extremely inconsitent. Could you please take a look at my code? I am new to Pytorch, maybe there is something wrong with my method and code. Final accuracy tested on test set is 86%. Thank you!

[image]

```
        learning_rate = 1e-1
        num_epochs = 100
        patience = 10
        batch_size = 100
        weights = [4, 1]    
        
        model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
        
        # Replace last layer       
        num_features = model.fc.in_features
        
        model.fc = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Linear(num_features, 512),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                nn.Linear(512, 64),
                nn.Dropout(0.5, inplace=True),
                nn.Linear(64, 2))
    
        class_weights = torch.FloatTensor(weights).cuda()
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
        optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        running_loss = 0
        losses = []
        
            # To freeze the residual layers
        
            for param in model.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = False
            for param in model.fc.parameters():
                param.requires_grad = True
            
            # Find total parameters and trainable parameters
            total_params = sum(p.numel() for p in model.parameters())
            print(f'{total_params:,} total parameters.')
            total_trainable_params = sum(
                p.numel() for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad)
            print(f'{total_trainable_params:,} training parameters.')
```

24,590,082 total parameters.
1,082,050 training parameters.

```
# initialize the early_stopping object
early_stopping = pytorchtools.EarlyStopping(patience=patience, verbose=True)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    ##########################    
    #######TRAIN MODEL########
    ##########################
    epochs_loss=0
    
    ##Switch to train mode
    model.train()
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dl):
        # Move tensors to the configured device
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        # Forward pass
       
        
        # Backprpagation and optimization
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images).to(device)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        #calculate train_loss
        train_losses.append(loss.item())
    
    ##########################    
    #####VALIDATE MODEL#######
    ##########################
    model.eval()
    for images, labels in val_dl:
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)
        outputs = model(images).to(device)
        loss = criterion(outputs,labels)
        valid_losses.append(loss.item())
    
    # print training/validation statistics 
    # calculate average loss over an epoch
    train_loss = np.average(train_losses)
    valid_loss = np.average(valid_losses)
#     print(train_loss)
    avg_train_losses.append(train_loss)
    avg_valid_losses.append(valid_loss)
    
    print_msg = (f'train_loss: {train_loss:.5f} ' + f'valid_loss: {valid_loss:.5f}')
    
    print(print_msg)

    
    # clear lists to track next epoch
    train_losses = []
    valid_losses = []
    
    early_stopping(valid_loss, model)
    print(epoch)
        
    if early_stopping.early_stop:
        print("Early stopping")
        break
```

Comment: Your code looks ok to me but looks like excessive overfitting. You could reduce learnable parameters and see what happens? How many images do you have in training set?